# ExpressJS, Stripe, Typescript, BodyParser I can not identify the type

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, types

So im doing a post on my express server. I'm using typescript

I send an undefined value from my URL in the body (Angular) to the Backend (Express Server).

Before the Object leaves the Frontend via http post method it is console.logged as undefined as expected. it is not defined.

It shall be undefined. its a case I want to include.

When i listen on that specific post on the backend.. i tried something like

```js
if(vendorId){    
    // Mongoose Schemes and other stuff in here...    
}
```

Which miserably failed. Well I error logged in the schema things cannot be undefined. so i was like... oh okay it's undefined. we just change the if condition

And this brought me to if(vendorID!==undefined)

Also didn't work it still entered the condition

With typeof it told me it's a string

And I was like well some plugin or some me programming must have went vendorID=""

Point is ..

```
if(vendorID !== "")
```

Also entered the condition

I ended up with long chains including:

```
if(vendorID==undefined && vendorID!=='' && vendorID==null)
```

There was an indication for null in the schematics so I tried and included it going through I'm pretty sure all permutations of the written above and also tried the below ones.

I'm completely not having any clue I'm aware that types like unknown values of undefined and all of that exists but from what I understand

I tried it all.

Is someone having any idea?

That's what i tried [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsQIM.png)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.log({vendorId})
```

You'll get

```
{ vendorId: "undefined" }
```

Your problem is that it's not undefined, null, or empty string
It's literally "undefined" string you'd get if you write

```
let v = undefined
let s1 = `${v}`
let s2 = v + ""
let s3 = String (v)
```

Comment: thank you. cant vote u up .. need website currency for it sorry

Comment: @Mathanuel you should be able to "mark as answer" tho, it's 1.5 upvotes

Comment: I assume it's the green symbol. done